# Search multiple columns in two mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, search

I have two tables and a search form to just search for a keyword. I am trying to search for that keyword on two table for multiple columns and if the query matches get the id column for further use. I have tried this (suppose "coupon" is the term user is searching for)

```
SELECT `ID` FROM `Profiles` AS `p` WHERE `p`.`Status` = 'Active' AND `p`.`Address`
LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`BusinessName` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`BusinessSubCategory`
LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`DescriptionMe` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`Tags` LIKE '%coupon%'
UNION SELECT `id` FROM `products` AS `d` WHERE `d`.`status` = 'approved' AND
`d`.`title` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `d`.`desc` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `d`.`tags` LIKE '%coupon%'
```

Here i want the id of profile and id of products that matches the keyword. I tried this and this is returning very strange results and looks like only profile ID. So, its a wrong query. What should be the query for this kind of search? INNER JOIN? Please give me some sample queries for this, i will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
SELECT `ID`,'profile_ID' FROM 
`Profiles` AS `p` 
WHERE `p`.`Status` = 'Active' AND `p`.`Address`
LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`BusinessName` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`BusinessSubCategory`
LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`DescriptionMe` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `p`.`Tags` LIKE '%coupon%'


UNION ALL

SELECT `id`, 'productID' FROM `products` AS `d` WHERE `d`.`status` = 'approved' AND
`d`.`title` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `d`.`desc` LIKE '%coupon%' OR `d`.`tags` LIKE '%coupon%'
```

Comment: Its returning nothing, as i can see there is coupon keyword in two products's desc column. So, at least two products should return but nothing :(

Comment: @what is the status there then??

Comment: all products status are approved.

Comment: Okay now i know whats happening. Your new query is returning same thing as mine but first i thought its returning 2 from profiles but its returning any result on column name 'ID' but i was expecting results from products table on name 'id' and from profiles table on name 'ID' but thats not happening. :(

Comment: You did UNION in which if the profileID and product Id is same, you will get only 1 row, but in UNION ALL it will return 2 rows

Comment: Now run both the queries that is 1 for product and the other for profiles, please reply with the resultset, what you get of it

Comment: Okay, i ran the query for profile and get empty result, as expected. Then i ran query for product and get this id = 2, productID = productID. And there is a correction that there are only one product with coupon keyword in it so the result is correct

Comment: I ran the same query above and get 
ID = 2, profile_ID = productID

Comment: So I believe, you wanted this only?

Comment: I think i can do something on the php side atleast i will know the result is from which table by productID and profile_ID. Thanks for you so much help

Comment: ohhh then remove the second column in both the queries

Comment: hmm! what? if i will remove profile_ID and productID from queries how will i know the id is of what product or profile?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13903/discussion-between-prashank-and-sashi-kant)

Comment: sure, I have clicked on the link the network is pathetic here

Answer (score 2):

First off, I wouldn't use `AS p` when you're not doing an `INNER JOIN` etc... seems like overdoing it plus I guess you need parentheses after `AND` - surrounding the `OR`s as well if you explicity want the to find results where status is "Active".

How about:

```
    SELECT ID FROM Profiles WHERE Status = 'Active' AND (Address LIKE '%coupon%' OR BusinessName LIKE '%coupon%' OR BusinessSubCategory LIKE '%coupon%' OR DescriptionMe LIKE '%coupon%' OR Tags LIKE '%coupon%')
UNION SELECT id FROM products WHERE status = 'approved' AND (title LIKE '%coupon%' OR desc LIKE '%coupon%' OR tags LIKE '%coupon%')
```

Comment: I was changing the query repeatedly, i was trying INNER JOIN first and after that tried UNION so, i thought AS p or AS d will not affect the result.

Comment: The parentheses around the ORs though can make the difference depending on precisely what kind of result you want

Comment: syntax error near 'desc LIKE '%coupon%' OR tags LIKE '%coupon%') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: @Prashank: `DESC` should have backquotes around it: `\`DESC\`` Or (even better) change this column name to a non-reserved word.

Comment: Same thing its returning correct id of the product but on the column name of "ID"

Comment: oh, yeah of course desc has special meaning so you need it quoted! Should've seen that...it even turns blue hehe...thanks ypercube!